# Constrained discretisation of curve on parametric surface

Tags: 3d, constraints, mathematical-optimization, curve, discretization

I have a boundary curve on a parametric surface. The curves knots are expressed in surface uv coordinates. Evaluating a curve point to 3D coordinates is computationally very expensive.

I'm looking for a discretisation approach to distribute a minimum number of points on that curve while not exceeding constrained

- maximum 3d point distance
- maximum 3d angular tolerance (between three discretised points xor between two point surface normals)
- maximum 3d chord error

and while not falling below a

- minimum 3d point distance

Especially the minimum point distance constraint makes it hard to use the subdivision method.

Although it would be very charming I'm not forced to find an analytical solution but I'm even struggling finding an iterative approach which ends in reasonable time.

Comment: You want to have "maximum 3d point distance" and "minimum 3d point distance" at the same time?  You need to clarify what you are trying to minimize (or maximize) and what constraints you have.

Comment: @fang I want to maximise the point distance (and therefore minimise the number of total points) but, in case that the distance needs to get smaller because of other constraints like the angular or chord tolerance, not go below the minimum point distance. I guess it was unclear becaues of my bad english and i tried to update the question

Comment: I think you are looking for a way to uniformly distribute some points along a curve so that the arc length between two points will not be below a certain value. If this is the case, perhaps this article (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36652/evenly-distribute-points-along-a-path) can help.

Comment: @fang thanks for the link. It's not that easy for me as to just uniformly distribute, as i have to respect four constraints and also have to minimize the number of total points distributed. The angular and chord constraints will not hit on weakly curvy parts where the points would be distributed with the max allowed distance uniformly, but as soon as curvature increases, the angular or chord constrain will limit and the spacing will have to be shorter than the max distance (but not shorter than the min allowed distance). This also implies that there are cases which cannot be solved.

Comment: @OP: It is really unclear what your constraints are. You mentioned you want to have maximum 3d distance, maximum 3d angular tolerance and maximum  3d chord error. However, there is no way to find a single solution that maximize 3d distance, 3d angular tolerance and 3d chord error at the same time. At best, you can only maximize a weighted sum of them.

Comment: @fang the wording is unclear, you're right. I tried to update the question. I want to minimize the number of points but stay within the constraints, so not maximize 3d distance, angular tolerance and chord but not exceeding them while minimizing the number of points and also not fall below the minimum point distance.